# How can I center my unordered list?

Tags: html, css, center

I have a family tree created from `<ul>`s and `<li>`s but I've tried everything and I can't seem to center the whole tree properly.

I've tried centering `.tree` and also wrapping `.tree` in another div and center that but nothing seems to work!

http://jsfiddle.net/V8H6T/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="chairman"><span class="accent">Chairman / Owner</span><p>Name</p></a>



            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="financemanager"><span class="accent">Finance &<br>
                    Managing Director</span><span>Name</span></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="financeteam"><span class="accent">Finance
                        Team</span> <span>Name</span><br></a></li>

                        <li><a href="salesdirector"><span class="accent">Sales
                        Director</span><span>Name</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width:100%;
}

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

ul {
    line-height:20px;
}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}

/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #E9E9E9; color: black; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:#06C;
}

span.accent{
    background-color: #113963;
    display: block;
    margin: -5px -10px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: JSFiddle would he handy.

Comment: Oops...was that edited in? :)

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LywDL/?

Comment: @Paulie_D No, it was there from the start :)

Comment: Looks pretty centered to me. Ubuntu + FF26.0

Comment: @Adsy check the answer I posted below http://jsfiddle.net/V8H6T/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fch9L/)

```
.tree{
    width:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: OMG I didn't set a width!! :( it's been a long day haha. thanks loops

Comment: The exactness of the centering in this case depends on the specified width.  The content within `.tree` is not exactly centered, which is more obvious if you were to try `width: 500px`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it.

Add a wrapper `div.wrap` around `div.tree`:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="tree">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="chairman"><span class="accent">Chairman / Owner</span></a>

                <p>Name</p>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="financemanager"><span class="accent">Finance &<br>
                    Managing Director</span><span>Name</span></a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="financeteam"><span class="accent">Finance
                        Team</span> <span>Name</span><br></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="salesdirector"><span class="accent">Sales
                        Director</span><span>Name</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the CSS,

```
.wrap {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    text-align: center;
}
.tree {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Apply `display: inline-block` to `div.tree` to get the get the minimum width, and then use `text-align: center` in `div.wrap` to get the horizontal centering.

I also added `overflow: auto` to `.tree ul` to contain the floated elements within their
block formatting context.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8gBAV/

The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to specity the width of `.tree`, which will keep the layout a bit more flexible and responsive.

Comment: A fantastic answer! I would never have thought of this

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V8H6T/6/)

```
<div class="tree">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="chairman"><span class="accent">Chairman / Owner</span></a>

        <p>Name</p>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="financemanager"><span class="accent">Finance &<br>
                Managing Director</span><span>Name</span></a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="financeteam"><span class="accent">Finance
                    Team</span> <span>Name</span><br></a></li>

                    <li><a href="salesdirector"><span class="accent">Sales
                    Director</span><span>Name</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
    body {
  position:absolute;
     width:300px;
     height:200px;
     z-index:15;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;

}

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

ul {
    line-height:20px;
}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}

/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #E9E9E9; color: black; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:#06C;
}

span.accent{
    background-color: #113963;
    display: block;
    margin: -5px -10px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.tree{
margin: auto 25%;
min-width:300px;
width:50%;
```

}

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8H6T/7/)

**min-width:300px** will prevent the tree being misplaced when window is resized